# Create new multisite from existing and keep domain?

Tags: multisite, domain

Apologies if this is too basic a question, but I have an existing multisite installation and would like to move one of the subdirectory websites "out" and create a new multisite with it due to size and technical considerations.

The catch is I'd like to keep the current domain and not use a subdomain. So lets say my current multisite is mapped to example.com and has directories:

- example.com/apples
- example.com/bananas
- example.com/cherries

Is is possible to take create a new folder in public_html for 'bananas' and make example.com/bananas a new multisite installation?

Or will this not work because there's already an existing installation at the root and in the database, and its DNS is mapped to *example.com*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can set up multiple installs. You do need to be careful that you don't ever create anything in the "parent" multisite (at `example.com`) that has the same slug as the folder you place the "child" multisite (at `example.com/bananas`) - so in the bananas example, never create a Post, Page, Category, Tag, etc. with the slug `bananas` in the parent site.

You could also consider a Multi-Network - which is basically a MultiSite of MultiSites. Most plugins aren't compatible with these, so if you rely on a lot of plugins that may not be the way you want to go, but it can help ensure you don't have conflicting slugs that cause the "Do I show the actual folder, or the content at this slug?" conundrum.